# How do I trigger a jquery slider (NIVO SLIDER) to work in a jqModal window?

Tags: jquery, triggers

I hope someone can offer any help!!

I have web page that initiates a modal window using jqModal (http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/). The jqModal is calling an external html file that has a NIVO Slider.

When I look at the external html page by itself without the jqModal window, the NIVO SLIDER works well.

But when I look at the external page via jqModal, the slider does not work.

Here are my links:

Here is the external html: [link text](http://www.logicpkg.com/carton01.htm)

Here is the external html viewed with jqModal: [link text](http://www.logicpkg.com/learn_cartonstyles.htm) (Click on No. 1).

Any suggestions ould be awesome. I'm really stuck. Are the two scripts conflicting with each other? Do I need to trigger something in jqModal when it initiates?

Really need help.

Thank you

Here is the code for the external html page that has the NIVO SLIDER:

```
    <script src="/src/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/src/jquery/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/src/css/logicpak.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect:'random', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices:15,
    animSpeed:500, //Slide transition speed
    pauseTime:3000,
    startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav:false, //Next & Prev
    directionNavHide:false, //Only show on hover
    controlNav:false, //1,2,3...
    controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    controlNavThumbsFromRel:true, //Use image rel for thumbs
    controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...
    controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src
    keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows
    pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions
    captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity
    beforeChange: function(){},
    afterChange: function(){},
    slideshowEnd: function(){}, //Triggers after all slides have been shown
    lastSlide: function(){}, //Triggers when last slide is shown
    afterLoad: function(){} //Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
    });


    function loadPage(list) {
    location.href=list.options[list.selectedIndex].value
    }

    </script>


    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    </head>
```

HERE IS THE CODE FOR THE PAGE THAT INITIATES THE jqModal:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>

      <head>
      <title>Manuacturer of Folding Cartons</title>
      <meta content="feeding orphans around the world" name="description">
      <link href="/src/css/logicpak.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="/src/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/src/jquery/jqmodal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



      <script  type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function() {
      $('#ex1').jqm({ajax: 'carton01.htm', trigger: '.ex1trigger'});
      });
      </script>

      </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has something to do with the fact that you're wrapping the slider initialization code in `$(window).load()`, which will not be fired when the dialog content is loaded via AJAX, since the content is just being appended to the page and being styled as a dialog (not actually loaded in a new browser window).  This is why your example works when it's not in a dialog.

Since you're retrieving the HTML via AJAX, you could just move your slider initialization code to the `onLoad` handler of the jqModal (last parameter on the main page for the plugin):

```
$('#dialog').jqm({
    onLoad:function() {
        // slider code here.  This will be called when the AJAX
        // call returns.
    },
    ajax: 'page.html'
});
```

I would standardize the class of the element the slider plugin is called on so that you can make the onload function the same for every callback.  Something like this:

```
var setupSlider = function() {
    // common slider initialization code.
    $(".slider").nivoSlider({ ... });
}

$('#dialog').jqm({
    onLoad:setupSlider,
    ajax: 'page.html'
});
```

Comment: thanks andrew!  your code helped me add nivo to a site that is loading page content via ajax